# How to find out all queue configuration parameters hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are using CapacityScheduler for resource allocation/management. I am struggling to find out all configuration parameters for my queue, I tried below command it returns only few parameters.

```
hadoop queue -info xyzqueue
```

**Output**

> Queue Name : root.xyzqueue 
>   Queue State : running 
>   Scheduling Info :
>   Capacity: 1.8867924, MaximumCapacity: UNDEFINED, CurrentCapacity:
>   0.35409614

How can I find the others parameters showed on [hadoop wiki](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) for queue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the RM REST APIs for this.

From https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Scheduler_API:

[image: Queue Information]

`curl RM_URL/ws/v1/cluster/scheduler`

[image]

It's pretty comprehensive what the REST APIs return.